# how to choose and upload a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, import, text-files

I am writing a program where it asks you what text file the user wants to read then it begins to read whatever file name the user inputs. Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
import re

#CHOOSE FILE
print "Welcome to the Parsing Database"
raw_input=raw_input("enter file name to parse: ")

#ASSIGN HEADERS AND SEQUENCES
f=open("raw_input", "r")
header=[]
sequence=[]
string=""
for line in f:
    if ">" in line and string=="":
         header.append(line[:-2])
    elif ">" in line and string!="":
        sequence.append(string)
        header.append(line[:-2])
        string=""
    else:
        string=string+line[:-2]
sequence.append(string)
```

The first two lines work but then it says it cannot find the file that I inputted to read. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Parsing FASTA files by any chance ;)
What is your error or specific problem?

Comment: You shouldn't use `raw_input` as a variable name. Also, you're not asking what you specifically need help with, nor are you mentioning if you have any errors/roadblocks.

Comment: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw_input'` should already tell you what the problem is, you are trying to open a file named `"raw_input"` instead of using the variable you got the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think that `f = open("raw_input", "r")` needs to be `f=open(raw_input, "r")`, because you are trying to reference the string contained in the variable `raw_input`, as opposed to trying to open a file named raw_input. Also you should probably change the name of the variable to something more readable, because `raw_input()` is a function used in your code as well as a variable, which makes it hard to read. Are there any other *specific* problems you are having with your code?

Comment: thanks that was my problem I had the quotation marks and it was messing me up

Comment: there's no real problem on naming it raw_input because the functions is raw_input(), but of course is better to create namespaced variables like file_raw_input or any other not taken.

Comment: @erm3nda that bit was more of a contextual suggestion because it looked like the OP was having trouble differentiating between various different bits of syntax (there is a much better way to say that)

Comment: If you edit their script then fix just raw_input name still doesn't work. Him needs more than just a suggestion.

Comment: Well they said it fixed their problem, so I assume the solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`f=open("raw_input", "r")`

"raw_input" is a plain string. You have to referente to it as `raw_input`.

Also, there's no lines if you don't use `.read()` with `open()` method so you can't parse them. Read lines from a file given from `raw_input` can be done doing that:

```
import sys
import os
import re

#CHOOSE FILE
print "Welcome to the Parsing Database"
raw_input_file=raw_input("enter file name to parse: ")

#ASSIGN HEADERS AND SEQUENCES
testfile = open(raw_input_file, "r")
secuence = []
for line in testfile.read().splitlines():
    secuence.append(line)
for i in secuence:
    print i
testfile.close()
```